# Puppeteer: How to use promise in evaluate?

Tags: puppeteer

```
var wait = await page3.evaluate(()=> {
    $('.modal').hide()
    setTimeout(()=>{
      return true
    }, 3000);
});
```

Ex: wait 3 second in evaulate

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You return a promise and resolve it when you want. Returning a promise will make it wait until it's resolved.

```js
var wait = await page3.evaluate(() => {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        $('.modal').hide()
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(true)
        }, 3000);
    });
});
```